# Why 95%CIs of One sample tests of proportions were different in Stata and R

Tags: r, stata

R

```
 > prop.test(x =44, n = 63, p = 0.8, alternative = "two.sided", correct = FALSE)

    95 percent confidence interval:
    **0.5763963 0.7976231**
```

Stata

```
. prtesti 63 44 0.8, count

  95% Conf. Interval
 **.5850839    .8117415**
```

Why 95%CIs of One sample tests of proportions were different in Stata and R，Thanks!

Comment: can you post the stata code

Comment: @rawr I think they did. If you google "stata prtesti" you'll find some documentation.

Comment: @joran the source code

Comment: Are the p-values different, too?

Comment: @Roland R: p-value = 0.04382  Stata: Pr(|Z| > |z|) = 0.0438

Comment: So, how does Stata calculate the CIs? I can study the R code, but don't have access to Stata.

Comment: Stata used Simple asymptotic method
R used score method and score method incorporating continuity correction.

Newcombe RG. Two-sided confidence intervals for the single proportion: comparison of seven methods. Stat Med 1998; 17(8):857-872. PMID:9595616

Page 859, Method 1(Stata) Method 3 and 4(R)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rprtest.pdf suggests that Stata is using the normal approximation.  The `epitools` package provides a range of binomial CI calculators:

Normal approximation (matches Stata):

```
binom.approx(44,63)
   x  n proportion     lower     upper conf.level
1 44 63  0.6984127 0.5850839 0.8117415       0.95
```

Exact (matches `binom.test()` in base R):

```
binom.exact(44,63)
   x  n proportion     lower     upper conf.level
1 44 63  0.6984127 0.5697502 0.8076894       0.95
```

Wilson's formula (matches `prop.test()` in base R):

```
binom.wilson(44,63)
   x  n proportion     lower     upper conf.level
1 44 63  0.6984127 0.5763963 0.7976231       0.95
```

EDIT (Nick Cox)  Some further Stata results, here from `cii` which accepts input calculator-style:

```
. cii 63 44, wald

                                                     -- Binomial Wald ---
    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Err.       [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
             |         63    .6984127    .0578219        .5850839    .8117415
```

The default is so-called "exact" (Clopper-Pearson):

```
. cii 63 44

                                                     -- Binomial Exact --
    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Err.       [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
             |         63    .6984127    .0578219        .5697502    .8076894


. cii 63 44, wilson

                                                     ------ Wilson ------
    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Err.       [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
             |         63    .6984127    .0578219        .5763963    .7976231

. cii 63 44, jeffreys

                                                     ----- Jeffreys -----
    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Err.       [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
             |         63    .6984127    .0578219        .5781254    .8009394
```

The moral is simple. In any decent statistical software, several options are available for binomial confidence intervals. Just read the documentation to know what is the default for your software, and pay attention to other options that are available.

END OF EDIT

Comment: Stata offers several different confidence intervals through `cii`.